# titleview on navigation bar not visible in views after segues

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, navigationbar

I am making an iPhone application, and would like to display a logo in the titleview position of my navigation bar. I've made a subclass of UINavigationController and added the following line in viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"titlelogo.png"]];
```

(this may seem like a waste for just one line, but i'm using it in multiple places and I don't want to use [UINavigationBar appearance] for various reasons)

This works fine for the immediate child of the navigation controller - I see the logo. However, when I push segue to another view, the logo does not carry over, even though they are (to the best of my knowledge) part of the "same" navigation controller.

(for reference) -> MyNavigationController -> SomeViewController -> SomeOtherViewController

I have also tried going into the viewDidLoad of SomeOtherViewController with a:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"titlelogo.png"]];
```

This still does not show the logo.

After some poking around, I have discovered that if 1) I do not have that line in the navigationcontroller's viewDidLoad and 2) I do have the second line in the SomeOtherViewController's viewDidLoad, then:

Start: Viewing SomeViewController. No logo.
Click to push segue: The logo now appears on SomeViewController's bar, before disappearing.
I am now viewing SomeOtherViewController: which has no logo.
Click back: SomeViewController's navigation bar still has the logo.

Obviously I am misunderstanding something about how a navigationcontroller works. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right you could also do it with another approach and just replace the whole **NavigationBar** with an image? There you could place your icon.

Because changing the whole NavigationBar is quite easy.

```
if ([self.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector( setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]) {
  [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

This code you need to put in the `viewDidLoad` method of the **NavigationController**. Then it should also be working in ViewControllers you push on the stack of the NavigationController.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = yourCustomView;
```

istead of

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = yourCustomView;
```

And do not touch `self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView` at all. At first I tried to set both of them to `yourCustomView`, and my custom view appeared for a split second and then was gone I have no idea where :)